# problems with sending email thro blat via gmail

Tags: gmail, blat

stunnel -install -quiet 
stunnel -start -quiet 
rem 7z a archive.7z @listfile.txt
blat -body "..." -server localhost:587 -f thisisayndctest@gmail.com -to thisisayndctest@gmail.com -u thisisayndctest@gmail.com -pw genius -attach listfile.txt

stunnel -stop -quiet 
stunnel -uninstall -quiet

i keep getting the error 
Blat v2.6.2 w/GSS encryption (build : Feb 25 2007 12:06:19)

Error: Server refused connection.

can you help  me to figure out how to fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your stunnel config, and the command you're using to send the email, I'm assuming, is the top command? That's very confusing... What command did you use to install blat with?

Comment: Try adding -port <port> after -server localhost:587